# How to update /etc/os-release

Tags: debian, upgrade, operating-system, debian-buster

I installed debian buster on a server while it was the debian testing release.  Now that buster is the current stable release, I've updated `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, and `apt-get dist-upgrade`.  However my `/etc/os-release` file reads `PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid"` instead of buster.  `/etc/issue` also indicates bullseye/sid.

How do I safely update the `/etc/os-release` file, and any others that indicate a testing version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `/etc/os-release` and `/etc/issue` are in the [base-files](https://packages.debian.org/buster/base-files) package.

Make sure you have something like the following in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster main
```

Followed by `sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get -y install base-files`.